# Clarification about solving cubic equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots, cubics

I'm trying to understand a statement written on Wikipedia about solving cubic equations. In particular this part:

> A ''cubic formula'' for the roots of the general cubic equation (with $a\neq 0$) $$ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d = 0$$ can be deduced from every variant of Cardano's formula.
> The formula being rather complicated, it is worth splitting it in smaller formulas.Let $\begin{align} \Delta_0 &= b^2 - 3ac,\\ \Delta_1 &= 2b^3 - 9abc + 27a^2d. \end{align}$
> Then
> $$C = \sqrt[3]{\frac{\Delta_1 \pm \sqrt{\Delta_1^2 - 4 \Delta_0^3}}2}$$
> where the symbols $\sqrt{{~}^{~}}$ and $\sqrt[3]{{~}^{~}}$ are interpreted as "any" square root and "any" cube root, respectively. The sign $\pm$ before the square root is either $+$ or $-$; the choice is almost arbitrary, and changing it amounts to choosing a different square root.
> Then, one of the roots is $x = - \dfrac{1}{3a}\left(b+C+\dfrac{\Delta_0}{C}\right).$
> The other two roots can be obtained by changing the choice of the cube root in the definition of $C$, or, equivalently by multiplying $C$ by a primitive root of unity, that is $\dfrac{–1 \pm \sqrt{–3}}{2}$. In other words, the three roots are $x_k = - \frac{1}{3a}\left(b+\xi^kC+\frac{\Delta_0}{\xi^kC}\right), \qquad k \in \{0,1,2\}$, where $ξ = \dfrac{–1 \pm \sqrt{–3}}{2}.$

First question: what does it mean "the choice is ALMOST completely arbitrary?" In what sense is ALMOST?

Second question: I tried to apply this to the following cubic $x^3 - 3x^2 + 2x - 2 = 0$.

I calculated what necessary that is $\Delta_0 = 3$, $\Delta_1 = -54$. Then
$C = \sqrt[3]{\dfrac{-54 \pm \sqrt{54^2 - 12}}{2}}$.

If I choose the plus sign, then $C \approx 0.391$ and it results $x_0 \approx 3.68$.

If I choose the minus sign, then $C \approx 3-77$ and it results $x_0 \approx 2.52$. Only the second choice leads to a very good solution for the cubic (the two others are real).

So it appears that if I chose the plus sign I would have not gotten the right solution. How can I know what sign to choose, because it is not arbitrary, and that "almost" arbitrary needs clarification.

Comment: *"Only the second choice leads to a very good solution for the cubic (the two others are real)"* ... The roots of $x^3-3x^2+2x-2=0$ are not all real. (See, for instance, [this WolframAlpha calculation](https://wolframalpha.com/input?i=x%5E3-3x%5E2%2B2x-2%3D0).)

Comment: As for why the choice of square root is "ALMOST arbitrary": Well, you want to avoid a square root choice that makes $C=0$, since it appears later in a denominator. Apart from that, the choice really is arbitrary. That said, one option may make for easier or more-convenient calculations by a human. (A computer wouldn't care.) For instance, faced with $\sqrt[3]{-1\pm\sqrt{49}}$, the *arbitrary* "$\pm$" is *probably* best considered "$-$". The point being, you shouldn't say to yourself "Since it's arbitrary, I'll just always choose $+$."

Comment: @blue note that $C=0$ is possible only if $\Delta_0=0$ which gives a degenerate root. Thus an irreducible cubic is always soluble by this formula, though resolving the formula requires trigonometric functions if there are three real roots.

Comment: @Blue Sorry, I miswrote. I meant not real!

Answer (score 3):

Begin with the fact that you forgot to cube the $\Delta_0$ term inside the square root.

Thus properly,

$C=\sqrt[3]{\dfrac{-54\pm\sqrt{54^2-\color{blue}{(4×3^3)}}}{2}}$

If done properly, both signs will eventually render the same value for $C+(\Delta_0/C)(\approx-4.56)$, and this should lead to a good root for the cubic ($\approx2.52$).

Answer (score 2):

$\sqrt{54^2-12}$ is less than $54,$ so there's no way you get a positive value for $C$ when choosing the plus sign.

Comment: Yes, I miswrote the signs. Yesterday I was particularly asleep but I needed to ask the question the same :D